# How to Change or replace a part of URL string in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have one url which contains special character like 
`#1#` or `#2#`

`http://10.10.10.10:8000/admin/taskinstance/?flt1_dag_id_equals=#1#&flt2_state_equals=#2#`

I want to change with some other value like in place of `#1#` I need `"hello"` and In place of `#2#` I need `"there"`, I tried with some code, but it's not working

```
var str = response.data;
var mapObj = {
   #1#:dagId,
   #2#:state
};
str = str.replace(/#1#|#2#/gi, function(matched){
   return mapObj[matched];
});
```

In response.data I am getting same URL which I have mention above,

I am getting:

> SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token for line no 3.

Is something is wrong in syntax?

I am fine with any syntax angularjs or javascript.

Comment: quote your keys `"#1#":dagId` - note that any `#` left in the string after the replace will likely break things if you send it off to a server.

Comment: With AngularJS, you should be using routing modules: `ngRoute` or `ui.router`. They can simplify your parameters, so that you don't need to replace anything

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the regex a bit by wrapping strings with parenthesis. Your object is not valid as well:

```js
var str = 'http://10.10.10.10:8000/admin/taskinstance/?flt1_dag_id_equals=#1#&flt2_state_equals=#2#';
var mapObj = {
   "#1#":"dagId",
   "#2#":"state"
};
str = str.replace(/(#1#)|(#2#)/gi, function(matched){
  return mapObj[matched];
});
console.log(str)
```